# Angular - Pass Interpolation expression as component parameter

Tags: angular, templates, interpolation, angular-components, angular-template

I am building a component that act as a dropdown list.
Since this is meant to be used generally, I would like that any list of objects could be displayed with the dropdown.

```
<dropdown [options]="list" [itemKey]="'itemkey'" [displayExpression]="Item no {{attr}}" (selectedItem)="getSelectedItem($event)"></dropdown>
```

I know I could also pass a template, but I think that passing an expression to be interpolated would be more simple for the developer.

1. How can I send the string interpolation? Should I pass with single quotes?
2. How can I interpolate the string inside the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing the template is really a more flexible way of achieving what you expected, but, if template is too heavy for you, a simple thing would be also passing a label getter

```
// ts
getItemLabel(item) {return `${item.name} is an item`}

// html
<dropdown [labelGetter]="getItemLabel">

// dropdown html
<label>{{labelGetter(item)}}</label>
```